# How to determine the length of an array of structs inside another struct

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to write a function that acts on a member of a struct that is in an array of structs that is a member of another struct :).  The first thing I need to do is find out the length of the array of structs, but I keep getting the error `expression must be class type.`

What would be the appropriate way for me to get the length of this array? (PS. The function has to take the `Student` structure as an argument.)

The structs:

```
struct Class
{
    string title; 
    int units;
    char grade;

};
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[500];
};
```

My function looks something like this:

```
void gpaCalculate (Student s)
{
    int size = s.classes.size() ;
    //Lots of awesome code
}
```

Comment: Use `std::array` for fixed-size arrays and usually `std::vector` otherwise. Both have a `size` member function. Arrays are built-in, so they don't have any members or anything.

Comment: If you really want code as per the question, make the magic number 500 a const "MAX_CLASSES" or similar. As chris points out, there are better solutions. Actual problem is that you are trying to call `size()` on a native array (which doesn't actually have methods)

Comment: It might also benefit you to pass `s` by const reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[500];
};
```

indicates that a `Student` can attend to maximum 500 classes, and that this is some school assignment where you are expected/required to use raw arrays, instead of the otherwise much more appropriate `std::vector`.

First, the **magic number** 500 should be made a constant, like so:

```
int const maxClasses = 500;
```

Then in each `Student` object you need to store the actual number of classes this student attends to:

```
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    int nClasses;
    Class classes[maxClasses];

    Student()
        : name(), gpa( 0.0 ), nClasses( 0 ), classes()
    {}
};
```

The constructor ensures that `gpa` and `nClasses` will be zeroed.

Since they're of built-in types that's otherwise not guaranteed (per the principle that you don't pay for what you don't use, so it's *your* decision).

Comment: Nitpick; even primitives will be zeroed if they are allocated statically. +1

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question "How do I determine the length of an array?", use `(sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array))`, as in

```
void gpaCalculate (Student s)
{
    int size = (sizeof s.classes) / sizeof(*s.classes);
    //Lots of awesome code
}
```

Note: this will not work with variable-length array parameters.
In answer to the question "How should I store a list of items in C++", generally you should use a vector.  Vectors tend to be easier to work with than arrays.  For example, vectors unlike arrays can change size.

Comment: BTW, the type safe way of doing that in C++11 would be: `template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr size_t array_size( T(&)[N] ) { return N; }` (typesafe as in passing a pointer won't yield the wrong value, but rather fail to compile)

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed the structures to C++ classes? Then you could create a function to access the size of the array of Classes. you could easily call the gpaCalulate function as a function of the Class class.

Comment: You can create functions for a `struct`, without changing to `class` as well. But the problem remains: You can't determine the size of the array stored inside the `class`/`struct`.